# Mascara para campo de linha digital de boletos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Alguém saberia informar se existe alguma mascara para a linha digitavel de boletos?

Estou com uma tela onde é exibida a listagem de boletos de um cliente e exibo também a linha digitavel de forma inteira, sem pontos ou separações, visto que este registro vem de um webservice. E no caso de boletos vencidos eu exibo um link para o cliente acessar diretamente o site do banco e digitando a linha digitavel do boleto ele consegue gerar um boleto com uma nova data de vencimento.

No entanto no site do banco a linha digitavel é separada em varios campos, não sendo possivel digitar o numero por inteiro.

Sendo assim, alguem conhece uma biblioteca ou um script que já faz essa conversão?

Comment: Se você tiver a regra (acredito que isso seja padronizado) deve se fácil pq os campos são baseados por comprimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o plugin [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) pode criar a máscara passando apenas o padrão, o `9` significa que apenas números são aceitos.

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="boleto"/>
```

javascript:

```
$("#boleto").inputmask({mask: '99999.99999 99999.999999 99999.999999 9 99999999999999'});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var codigo_barras = '00190500954014481606906809350314337370000000100'

function mascaraBoleto(codigoBarras) {
/*
  Posição 01-03 = Identificação do banco (exemplo: 001 = Banco do Brasil)
  Posição 04-04 = Código de moeda (exemplo: 9 = Real)
  Posição 05-09 = 5 primeiras posições do campo livre (posições 20 a 24 do código de barras)
  Posição 10-10 = Dígito verificador do primeiro campo
  Posição 11-20 = 6ª a 15ª posições do campo livre (posições 25 a 34 do código de barras)
  Posição 21-21 = Dígito verificador do segundo campo
  Posição 22-31 = 16ª a 25ª posições do campo livre (posições 35 a 44 do código de barras)
  Posição 32-32 = Dígito verificador do terceiro campo
  Posição 33-33 = Dígito verificador geral (posição 5 do código de barras)
  Posição 34-37 = Fator de vencimento (posições 6 a 9 do código de barras)
  Posição 38-47 = Valor nominal do título (posições 10 a 19 do código de barras)
*/
    if(codigoBarras.length !== 47){
    return codigoBarras;
  }
  
    let mascaraAjustada = codigoBarras.substring(0,5) + '.' + codigoBarras.substring(5,10)
  + ' ' + codigoBarras.substring(10,15) + '.' + codigoBarras.substring(15,21) + ' ' 
  + codigoBarras.substring(21,26) + '.' + codigoBarras.substring(26,32) + ' ' 
  + codigoBarras.substring(32,33) + ' ' 
  + codigoBarras.substring(33,47)
  
    return mascaraAjustada;

}

console.log(mascaraBoleto(codigo_barras));
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).